# How to put all objects/property into the root of the object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this object:

```
const object = {
  profile: {
    name: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
  },
  email: "johndoe@email.com",
  address: {
    street: "Street J",
    numero: 123
  },
  role: "admin"
};
```

How can I make it flat? So all the data is in the root of the object? To look like this:

```
const object = {
  name: "John",
  lastName: "Doe"
  email: "johndoe@email.com",
  street: "Street J",
  numero: 123
  role: "admin"
};
```

I've been breaking my head but can't achieve what I need. Also I don't know if there will be nested objects, it may.
I've tried using `Object.entries` and trying to run over the array but it's not working.

Thanks

Comment: Will depend on the object. Is this structure defined? Or if it is going to very nested, better off using a library like lodash

Comment: @TusharShahi the structure is not defined. I'll take a look on Loadash Thanks